# Библиотека D2XX под Android, как правильно читать ответы разной длины?

Tags: java, android, com, микроконтроллеры, rs232

Проблема в следующем, разные команды дают ответ разной длины, в примере который я взял там эта длина жестко прописана в 256 значений, но я принимаю команды разной длины от 8 и до 123.

Как правильно сделать чтобы принимать значение с любой длиной ?

К примеру те команды что в коде нижу они возвращают ответ длиной 96 значений, если в переменой READBUF_SIZE сменить на 96 то тогда все супер, но как быть тогда с другими командами ?

Код который я брал для примера вот - [ссылка](https://github.com/ksksue/Android-FTDI-UART-Sample)

Библиотека которую я использую: [тыц](http://www.ftdichip.com/Android.htm)

Вот ответ который я получаю когда `READBUF_SIZE  = 256`

```
[1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -126, 10, -126, 10, -84, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -106, -10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Ответ длиной 96 значений, но на самом дели он пришел в 256 значений.
Если же сменить в переменой значение на 96 то тогда с этой командой все будет ОК, но как тогда получать другие разной длины ?

Вот мой код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static D2xxManager ftD2xx = null;
private FT_Device ftDev;

static final int READBUF_SIZE  = 256;
byte[] rbuf  = new byte[READBUF_SIZE];
char[] rchar = new char[READBUF_SIZE];
int mReadSize=0;

boolean mThreadIsStopped = true;
Handler mHandler = new Handler();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
        ftD2xx = D2xxManager.getInstance(this);
    } catch (D2xxManager.D2xxException ex) {
        Log.e("MyLog",ex.toString());
    }

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED);
    filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED);
    registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, filter);
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
}

//Fires after the OnStop() state
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(mUsbReceiver);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void OnClickOpenDevice(View view){
    Log.i("MyLog", "Button open device");
    openDevice();
}

public void OnClickOnOne (View view){
    if(ftDev == null) {
        return;
    }

    synchronized (ftDev) {
        if(ftDev.isOpen() == false) {
            Log.e("MyLog", "onClickWrite : Device is not open");
            return;
        }

        ftDev.setLatencyTimer((byte) 16);
        byte[] send = new byte[]{1, 5, 0, 5, 0, 1, 28, 11};
        ftDev.write(send, send.length);
    }
}

public void OnClickOffOne(View view){
    if(ftDev == null) {
        return;
    }

    synchronized (ftDev) {
        if(ftDev.isOpen() == false) {
            Log.e("MyLog", "onClickWrite : Device is not open");
            return;
        }

        ftDev.setLatencyTimer((byte) 16);
        byte[] send = new byte[]{1, 5, 0, 1, 0, 1, 93, -54};
        ftDev.write(send, send.length);
    }
}

private void openDevice() {
    if(ftDev != null) {
        if(ftDev.isOpen()) {
                //updateView(true);
                SetConfig(19200, D2xxManager.FT_DATA_BITS_8, D2xxManager.FT_STOP_BITS_1, D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_NONE, (byte)0);
                ftDev.purge((byte) (D2xxManager.FT_PURGE_TX | D2xxManager.FT_PURGE_RX));
                ftDev.restartInTask();
                new Thread(mLoop).start();
        }
        return;
    }

    int devCount = 0;
    devCount = ftD2xx.createDeviceInfoList(this);

    Log.d("MyLog", "Device number : " + Integer.toString(devCount));

    D2xxManager.FtDeviceInfoListNode[] deviceList = new D2xxManager.FtDeviceInfoListNode[devCount];
    ftD2xx.getDeviceInfoList(devCount, deviceList);

    if(devCount <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    if(ftDev == null) {
        ftDev = ftD2xx.openByIndex(this, 0);
    } else {
        synchronized (ftDev) {
            ftDev = ftD2xx.openByIndex(this, 0);
        }
    }

    if(ftDev.isOpen()) {
            //updateView(true);
            SetConfig(19200, (byte) 8, (byte) 1, (byte) 0, (byte) 0);
            ftDev.purge((byte) (D2xxManager.FT_PURGE_TX | D2xxManager.FT_PURGE_RX));
            ftDev.restartInTask();
            new Thread(mLoop).start();
    }
}

private void closeDevice() {
    //updateView(false);
    if(ftDev != null) {
        ftDev.close();
    }
}

private Runnable mLoop = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int i;
        int readSize;
        mThreadIsStopped = false;
        while(true) {
            if(mThreadIsStopped) {
                break;
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            synchronized (ftDev) {
                readSize = ftDev.getQueueStatus();
                if(readSize>0) {
                    mReadSize = readSize;
                    if(mReadSize > READBUF_SIZE) {
                        mReadSize = READBUF_SIZE;
                    }
                    ftDev.read(rbuf, mReadSize);

                    // cannot use System.arraycopy
                    for(i=0; i<mReadSize; i++) {
                        rchar[i] = (char)rbuf[i];
                    }
                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.i("MyLog", "Handler post: " + Arrays.toString(rbuf));
                            Log.e("MyLog", "Длина: " + rbuf.length);

                        }
                    });

                } // end of if(readSize>0)
            } // end of synchronized
        }
    }
};

public void SetConfig(int baud, byte dataBits, byte stopBits, byte parity, byte flowControl) {
    if (ftDev.isOpen() == false) {
        Log.e("MyLog", "SetConfig: device not open");
        return;
    }

    // configure our port
    // reset to UART mode for 232 devices
    ftDev.setBitMode((byte) 0, D2xxManager.FT_BITMODE_RESET);

    ftDev.setBaudRate(baud);

    switch (dataBits) {
        case 7:
            dataBits = D2xxManager.FT_DATA_BITS_7;
            break;
        case 8:
            dataBits = D2xxManager.FT_DATA_BITS_8;
            break;
        default:
            dataBits = D2xxManager.FT_DATA_BITS_8;
            break;
    }

    switch (stopBits) {
        case 1:
            stopBits = D2xxManager.FT_STOP_BITS_1;
            break;
        case 2:
            stopBits = D2xxManager.FT_STOP_BITS_2;
            break;
        default:
            stopBits = D2xxManager.FT_STOP_BITS_1;
            break;
    }

    switch (parity) {
        case 0:
            parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_NONE;
            break;
        case 1:
            parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_ODD;
            break;
        case 2:
            parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_EVEN;
            break;
        case 3:
            parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_MARK;
            break;
        case 4:
            parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_SPACE;
            break;
        default:
            parity = D2xxManager.FT_PARITY_NONE;
            break;
    }

    ftDev.setDataCharacteristics(dataBits, stopBits, parity);

    short flowCtrlSetting;
    switch (flowControl) {
        case 0:
            flowCtrlSetting = D2xxManager.FT_FLOW_NONE;
            break;
        case 1:
            flowCtrlSetting = D2xxManager.FT_FLOW_RTS_CTS;
            break;
        case 2:
            flowCtrlSetting = D2xxManager.FT_FLOW_DTR_DSR;
            break;
        case 3:
            flowCtrlSetting = D2xxManager.FT_FLOW_XON_XOFF;
            break;
        default:
            flowCtrlSetting = D2xxManager.FT_FLOW_NONE;
            break;
    }

    // TODO : flow ctrl: XOFF/XOM
    // TODO : flow ctrl: XOFF/XOM
    ftDev.setFlowControl(flowCtrlSetting, (byte) 0x0b, (byte) 0x0d);
}


// done when ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    openDevice();
};

BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
            // never come here(when attached, go to onNewIntent)
            openDevice();
        } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
            closeDevice();
        }
    }
};
}
```